# Set Minimum item cost in Woocommerce Shipping method rates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

In Woocommerce, I have a Flat Rate Shipping set up with 1 Zone & 3 Shipping Options. In each of the Shipping Options I have Shipping Classes and in each of these Shipping Class Costs for each of my major product categories. My problem is that I can't seem to correctly set a minimum fee for the Shipping Class Costs. For example, when I use something like this in a Shipping Class Cost `1.43 * [qty] [fee min_fee="20"]` it multiplies my product cost by 20, instead of simply having the fee be a minimum of 20 for the cart.

How can I fix this, so that when someone goes to order an item the shipping cost defaults to the fee of 20, but after 20 simply uses the 1.43 per product in the cart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a shipping default starting cost of `20` + `1.43` by item use instead one of the following:

```
20+(1.43*[qty])
```

or

```
1.43*[qty]+[fee min_fee="20"]
```

---

But if you want to have a cost of `20` for the first item and + `1.43` by following items, use:

```
18.57+(1.43*[qty])
```

or

```
1.43*[qty]+[fee min_fee="18.57"]
```

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, is it possible to have a shipping fee apply to the first 5 or so items of the class? What I'm facing now is that it seems to be too large a fee

Comment: @codeforever Yes but this require a custom function hooked in `woocommerce_package_rates`… Here Are [all related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_package_rates) using this hook and [here my related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+woocommerce_package_rates) … Try yourself and if needed ask a new question including your code.