# How to set a shipping cost by item in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

In Woocommerce, when I add multiple products in cart, the shipping only applies to to 1 product. How should I change that to apply the cost to each item?

Like in the following image, the shipping cost for printer is applied but the LCD monitor is not.

[image]

How to set a shipping cost by item in Woocommerce?

Comment: There are so many rules to ecommerce with how your products and shipping rules are set up. You'll need to share more relative information to get the help you need.

Comment: Any feed back on the answer below please… Did you tried?

Answer (score 3):

In the Woocommerce Shipping Settings for **"Flat rate"** Shipping Method, there is many ways to get dynamic settings based on:

- Item quantity, using `[qty]` argument
- Total item cost, using `[cost]` argument
- A fee, using `[fee]` argument with additional parameters `percent`, `min_fee` and `max_fee`

You can also use `+`, `-`, `*` and `/` operators and parenthesis.

**Here are some example:**

1. `[qty]*2` - Cost by item
2. `4+([qty]*2.5)` - Initial cost with an additional cost by item
3. `[fee percentage='10' min_fee='' max_fee='20']` - Percentage fee limited to a max amount
4. `[fee percentage='10' min_fee='4' max_fee='']` - Percentage fee with a minimal cost

[image]

Related thread: [Set Minimum item cost in Woocommerce Shipping method rates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54962719/set-minimum-item-cost-in-woocommerce-shipping-method-rates/54963167#54963167)

---

**Advanced shipping cost customizations:**

It's possible to customize even more shipping costs using **`woocommerce_package_rates`** filter hook.

See [**all StackOverFlow related threads**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_package_rates) using **`woocommerce_package_rates`** filter hook.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have applied arguments and operators on shipping classes. The problem is if i add multiple products to the cart, it just adds the shipping cost of the bulkiest product. I want shipping cost of all the products (in the cart) to be added. How do I do that ?

Comment: @user3467773 Sorry, but for example if you use `[qty]*2` in one shipping class and `[qty]*3` to another shipping… it will add the correct amount by item and by shipping class, and not on the bulkiest one… when using shipping classes cost the main field need to be empty, only your shipping classes cost fields and "No shipping class" cost field need to be filled.

Comment: Could not find an option to work with weight or using `[weight]` . Is there such an option?

Comment: @rhand There are some free plugins that allow shipping calculation based on weight…